# Snap applications give segmentation fault error

Tags: snap, segmentation-fault, snap-store

After about 20 minutes of using the OS, all snap applications will suddenly stop working (including the snap store itself). After closing them, they do not relaunch. Trying to open from terminal gives "Segmentation fault" error. What is causing this, and why is it only affecting snap applications?

Comment: I had similar problems under 6.0 kernel. After I changed to 5.17, snaps are working normally. I have read on snapcraft forum that this bug has been submitted. I wait 6.1 kernel.

Comment: I recently put the 6.0.6 kernel on my system - I will go back to 5, thanks.

Comment: I have written it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Kernel 6.0 causes these segmentation faults. Move back to 5.17 or 5.15 kernels.

Comment: Is this still a problem? Is there a ticket/issue I can reference to review status of the issue?

Comment: I think this was fixed in 6.1 kernel.

Comment: Hmm. I'm using 6.2 and am experiencing this problem.